# is it possible to not load assets into memory with ng serve

Tags: angular-cli

While running ng serve from angular cli, as expected the app is loaded into memory, but it is also loading the entire assets folder with videos into memory also, which substantially increases memory uses by angular cli. Is there a way to prevent this and still use ng serve?

Comment: Instead of using `ng serve`, use `ng build --watch` and then use `lite-server` to serve the `dist` folder.

Answer (score 0):

When you running `ng serve` it is actually using [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) under the hood. So by default it is loading `assets` folder in to memory as it is configured on cli config - so the ansver is no, in that case all your links to static assets just wont work.

But I do not think that you have to store the videos inside your `assets` anyway. Why don't you upload the videos say on youtube and just have the links to that in your app?

More details on assets here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration

Comment: Uploading to some server will make offline development difficult. Perhaps what I am asking is not possible yet.